# Yii second query parameter

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have query to my database using Yii

```
$query = Task::find()
        ->where([Task::tableName().'.parent_id' => 0]);
$query->leftJoin(TaskModel::tableName(), [TaskModel::tableName().'.task_id' => Task::tableName().'.id']);
$query->andWhere([TaskModel::tableName().'.format' => null]);
$rows = $query
        ->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->orderBy([
            Task::tableName().'.status' => SORT_DESC,
            Task::tableName().'.`estimated_date`=0' => SORT_ASC,
            Task::tableName().'.estimated_date' => SORT_ASC
        ])
        ->all();
```

But that doesn't work, because at leftJoin, when I set relations between tables, second parameter sets string.

rawSql of my query:

```
SELECT `task`.* 
FROM `task` LEFT JOIN `task_model`
ON `task_model`.`task_id`='{{%task}}.id'
WHERE (`task`.`parent_id`=0) AND (`task_model`.`task_id` IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use string in this case:

```
$query->leftJoin(TaskModel::tableName(), TaskModel::tableName() . '.task_id = ' . Task::tableName() . '.id');
```

This case is explicitly mentioned in [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#join()-detail):

> Note that the array format of `where()` is designed to match columns to values instead of columns to columns, so the following would not work as expected: `['post.author_id' => 'user.id']`, it would match the `post.author_id` column value against the string `'user.id'`. It is recommended to use the string syntax here which is more suited for a join:
>
> ```
> 'post.author_id = user.id'
> ```